# rJava: pass 2 dimensional string array as function input

Tags: r, rjava

In my java class I write 3 test functions as follows:

```
public void try2dStringArray(String[][] arr) {
    System.out.println(arr.length);

}
public void try1dStringArray(String[] arr) {
    System.out.println(arr.length);

}
public void try2dDoubleArray(double[][] arr) {
    System.out.println(arr.length);

}
```

In R part I run the following:

```
library(rJava)
.jinit('/path/to/my/jar/app.jar')
obj <- .jnew('somepackage.Someclass')
doubleMatrix <- rbind(c(1,2), c(3,4))
stringMatrix <- rbind(c('a', 'b'), c('c', 'd'))
stringArray <- c('a', 'b')

result <- .jcall(obj,"V","try1dStringArray",
                 .jarray(stringArray, dispatch = T))
result <- .jcall(obj,"V","try2dDoubleArray",
                 .jarray(doubleMatrix, dispatch = T))
result <- .jcall(obj,"V","try2dStringArray",
                 .jarray(stringMatrix, dispatch = T))
```

Only the last one errors out:

```
Error in .jcall(obj, "V", "try2dStringArray", .jarray(stringMatrix, dispatch = T)) : 
  method try2dStringArray with signature ([[Ljava.lang.String;)V not found
```

How is `String[][]` different from `double[][]` in this case and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does `.jarray(lapply(apply(stringMatrix,1,function(x) lapply(x,.jnew,class="java/lang/String")),.jarray))` create a `String[][]` java object suitable for your method?

Comment: @nicola It doesn't seem to work: `Error in .jcall(obj, "V", "try2dStringArray", .jarray(lapply(apply(stringMatrix,  : 
  method try2dStringArray with signature ([Ljava/lang/Object;)V not found`

Comment: It seems that you got `Object[][]` instead of `String[][]`. I looked at the doc of `.jarray` and maybe using the argument `contents.class` will solve: `.jarray(apply(stringMatrix,1,.jarray),contents.class="java/lang/String")`. I also simplified a little the command. Hope this works.

Comment: @nicola It doesn't work neither: `Error in .jcall(obj, "V", "try2dStringArray", .jarray(apply(stringMatrix,  : 
  method try2dStringArray with signature ([Ljava/lang/String;)V not found`

Comment: The attempts I was making were wrong. But here is some mistery: if you try `obj$try2dStringArray(.jarray(stringMatrix, dispatch = T))` it should work (at least, it works for me, printing `2`). Maybe it's a bug in `.jcall`.

Comment: @nicola It works for me too if writing this way. Thanks! Do you want to write an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I wrote an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, I thought that `.jarray` wasn't able to properly create a `String[][]` java array from a `character` R `matrix`. I was wrong and the error received when the code in the OP is run testifies it:

```
.jcall(obj,"V","try2dStringArray",.jarray(stringMatrix, dispatch = T))
#Error in .jcall(obj, "V", "try2dStringArray", .jarray(stringMatrix, dispatch = T)) : 
#method try2dStringArray with signature ([[Ljava.lang.String;)V not found
```

As can be seen, the signature (`([[Ljava.lang.String;)V`) seems correct (the double `[[` should say that we actually passed a `String[][]` object), but for some reason `.jcall` can't find it.

However, in `rJava` methods can be called also with the syntax `obj$method(arg1,arg2,...)`, and in this way the method `try2dStringArray` is correctly called:

```
obj$try2dStringArray(.jarray(stringMatrix, dispatch = T))
#2
```

Comment: So, this is a bug of rJava, isn't it? with .jcall it does work, with obj$try.. it does...